# trigger command over network from/to Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I have two linux (gentoo) boxes `A` and `B`. Both are connected via LAN.

`A` has a camera with motion detection. If motion was detected I can trigger a command on `A`.

I want to send a ? **message/packet** to `B` so that `B` plays a sound on every motion event that occurs on `A`. 
(paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga)

How can I do this (without passwordless SSH setup), maybe netcat?

Answer (score 0):

On `B`, start a http server with Python, for example:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'OK')
        *** Put here your command *** 


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

On `A`, each time you detect a motion use `wget` or `curl` pointing to the URL of `B`, for example:

```
wget http://B's IP address:8000
```

or

```
curl http://B's IP address:8000
```